# Proguard obfuscating Annotations

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I need to keep all model classes to be unobfuscated, so I added this line in proguard rules to keep all model classes:

```
-keep class my_package_name.model.** { *; }
```

All model classes are getting kept by this command but still, it is obfuscating the annotations inside the Model classes. I tried adding the following line:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

But still, results are same. My model classes contain these two annotations:

```
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
```

How can I keep the two annotations unobfuscated?

Comment: It looks like you are using gson, so I would have a look to the recommended gson proguard configuration https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields.
Proguard removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.

Trying adding

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Annotation
```

For using GSON @Expose annotation

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

For Gson specific classes

```
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
```

Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)

```
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontnote sun.misc.**

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

Actually, there is a proguard config in official repo on github https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Answer (score 3):

-keep @package.annotationclassname public class *

Comment: I already tried this,but not working.It is still obfuscating the annotations

Comment: Can you please write your rule here? Maybe there is a mistake.

Comment: -keep @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName public class *

Answer (score 3):

The rule

```
-keep class com.google.gson.annotations.*
```

will keep all annotations in the package com.google.gson.annotations including the SerializedName and Expose ones that you have used.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your proguard : It's preventing specific classes to be obfuscated.

1. **Mandatory : `-dontshrink`.** : https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage
2. Not mandatory : try to use `-dontoptimize`.
3. I don't really understand the issue, are you referring to a field or inner class ? 
   If you have an inner class inside a class, you need to specify its inner fields. 
   For example, if this is the class :

   ```
   public class Parent {

   protected Child child;

   protected class Child {
       private String name;
       private int age;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public int getAge() {
           return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
           this.age = age;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

In the proguard, you need to specify `Child` class :

`-keep class com.package.name.Parent$Child {*; }`

Answer (score 1):

You may Need To Create an annotation called DontObfuscate in your project
for more check this
[Managing obfuscation with annotations](https://andersmurphy.com/2016/10/08/managing-obfuscation-with-annotations.html)