# Exception in getFieldOrder() when obfuscating JNA Structure using progaurd

Tags: java, proguard, jna, oshi

My un-obfuscated code works..

When run through Proguard obfuscation -- just 1 pass optimization
I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class com.sun.jna.platform.mac.SystemB$Timeval does not provide enough names [0] ([]) to match declared fields [2] ([tv_sec, tv_usec])
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.ensureAllocated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.ensureAllocated(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.getPointer(Unknown Source)
    at oshi.util.platform.mac.SysctlUtil.sysctl(Unknown Source)
    at oshi.software.os.mac.MacOperatingSystem.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at oshi.SystemInfo.createOperatingSystem(Unknown Source)
    at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Unknown Source)
    at oshi.SystemInfo.getOperatingSystem(Unknown Source)
```

I tried several on keep directive as follows:

```
-keep class com.sun.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class com.sun.jna.**{ *; }
-keep class * implements  com.sun.jna.**{ *; }

-keep class oshi.**{ *; }
-keep class * implements  oshi.**{ *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.sun.jna.** {
    <fields>;
   <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends oshi.** {
    <fields>;
   <methods>;
}
```

How can I configure Proguard to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with JNA 5.x, the `Structure` class fields are identified with the `@FieldOrder` annotation.  For the `Timeval` structure causing your problem, it's defined like this:

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "tv_sec", "tv_usec" })
class Timeval extends Structure {
    public NativeLong tv_sec; // seconds
    public int tv_usec; // microseconds
}
```

The stack trace indicates it's finding the `public` fields (correctly) but not finding the field order declared by the annotation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376659/proguard-obfuscating-annotations) indicates that Proguard will obfuscate annotations, which is likely the source of the problem.

[JNA's FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/fdb8695fb9b05fba467dadfe5735282f8bcc053d/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#jna-on-android) suggests the following syntax.  It's possible the more broad wildcard definition is necessary rather than explicitly defining `<fields>` and `<methods>`.

```
-dontwarn java.awt.*
-keep class com.sun.jna.* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.sun.jna.* { public *; }
```

Since the annotation is defined in JNA's Structure class as an `@interface`, the solution suggested by answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474109/proguard-keep-implementations-for-interface-annotated-with-keep) indicate the following should fix the problem:

```
# Annotated interfaces (including methods which are also kept in implementing classes)
-keep @com.sun.jna.Structure.FieldOrder interface * {
    *;
}
```

Other solutions that may work, more broadly:

- `-keepattributes Annotation`
- `-keepattributes *Annotation*`